# How to execute an action when x and y location enters another location?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, frame, contacts

I'm trying to make a little racing game for fun. So far I have two rectangles that successfully move and I have a map setup for them to race through.
My map is also made up of rectangles. Now previously I made a mistake by not giving my two racers a specific objectified name. So they're just two locations that move. Now what i'm trying to do is, to make the rectangle walls actually be walls so they don't just go through them. I've heard I can cover up my mistakes if I make the walls like arrays(not sure how) so they don't go through them. Is this correct? Is there any other way to do this? 
**Here is how it looks like so far:**
[image]

Thank you and here is my code. 
First class is the info for frames and black rectangle.
Second class is the info for the blue rectangles and the walls.

***First Class:***

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;

public class MyGame extends JPanel implements ActionListener, KeyListener {
    Timer t = new Timer(5, this);
    int x = 0, y = 0, velx =0, vely =0, g = 0;
    private Color color;

    public MyGame() {
        t.start();
        addKeyListener(this);
        setFocusable(true);
        setFocusTraversalKeysEnabled(false);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1300, 750);
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.setColor(color);
        g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);

    }


    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (x < 0) //stops us from going backwards past x = 0
        {
            velx = 0;
            x = 0;
        }

        if (y < 0) //stops us from going to the sky
        {
            vely = 0;
            y = 0;
        }

        if (y > 725) // stops us from going through the ground
        {
            vely = 0;
            y = 725;
        }
        if (x > 1250) // stops us from going through the wall
        {
            velx = 0;
            x = 1250;
        }

        x += velx;
        y += vely;
        repaint();
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        int code = e.getKeyCode();

        {
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) {
                vely = 2; // removing velx = 0 allows us to go vertically and horizontlly at the same time
                velx = 0;
            }
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_UP) {
                vely = -2; // same goes for here
                velx = 0;
            }
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
                vely = 0;
                velx = -2;
            }

            {
                if (code == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
                    vely = 0;
                    velx = 2;

                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }




    public static void main (String arge[]){

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(new Incoming());           
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
}
```

***Second Class:***

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;


public class Incoming extends MyGame {

private Color color;



int x = 0, y = 0; 
int velx = 0, vely = 0;

public Incoming() {
    color = Color.BLUE;
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle();


}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {


    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(color);
    g.fillRect(x, y, 50, 30);

    g.setColor(Color.blue);        

    g.drawRect(0, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(80, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(160, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(240, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(320, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(400, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(480, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(560, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(640, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(720, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(800, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(880, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(960, 100, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(1040, 100, 80, 30);

    g.drawRect(1040, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(1120, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(1200, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(960, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(880, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(800, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(720, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(640, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(560, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(480, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(400, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(320, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(240, 250, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(160, 250, 80, 30);

    g.drawRect(1040, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(960, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(880, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(800, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(720, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(640, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(560, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(480, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(400, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(320, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(240, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(160, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(80, 400, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(0, 400, 80, 30);

    g.drawRect(1040, 550, 80, 30);       
    g.drawRect(1120, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(1200, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(960, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(880, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(800, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(720, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(640, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(560, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(480, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(400, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(320, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(240, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(160, 550, 80, 30);

    g.drawRect(1040, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(960, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(880, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(800, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(720, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(640, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(560, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(480, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(400, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(320, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(240, 550, 80, 30);
    g.drawRect(160, 550, 80, 30);



}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    super.actionPerformed(e);
    if (x < 0) //stops us from going backwards past x = 0
    {
        velx = 0;
        x = 0;
    }

    if (y < 0) //stops us from going to the sky
    {
        vely = 0;
        y = 0;
    }

    if (y > 725) // stops us from going through the ground
    {
        vely = 0;
        y = 725;
    }

    if (x > 1250) // stops us from going through the wall
    {
        velx = 0;
        x = 1250;
    }

    if (y < 0.1)        
    {

        y = 50;
    }

    x += velx;
    y += vely;
    repaint();
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    super.keyPressed(e);
    int code = e.getKeyCode();

    {
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
            vely = 2; // removing velx = 0 allows us to go vertically and horizontlly at the same time
            velx = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
            vely = -2; // same goes for here
            velx = 0;
        }
        if (code == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
            vely = 0;
            velx = -2;
        }

        {
            if (code == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
                vely = 0;
                velx = 2;

            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    super.keyReleased(e);

}
}
```

Comment: Hoping that it will not disappoint or discourage you too much: There's so much "not right" with the code that it's hard to give an answer that fits on a Q&A site. You may start by creating a `List<Rectangle>` and fill this list with rectangles that correspond to all these `drawRect` calls. This list can then be used to replace the `drawRect` calls (you can just iterate over the list with a loop, and call `drawRect` for each element of the list), and later it can be used for collision detection, using `if (rectangle.intersects(playerRectangle))`. Then, you may write more focussed question.

Comment: How would I list rectangles? Could you please be a little more specific?

Comment: `List<Rectangle> rectangles = new ArrayList<Rectangle>()`, then `rectangles.add(new Rectangle(0, 100, 80, 30));`. (These rectangles could also be *created* in a loop - at last for each row). But these are basics, not sure whether it is appropriate to *explain* such things here...

Answer (score 1):

> How would I list rectangles?

See the `DrawOnCompnent` example from [Custom Painting Approaches](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/08/custom-painting-approaches/). It shows you how to paint from an ArrayList.